# Formatting numbers to currency format in Indesign using GREP

Tags: regex, adobe-indesign

I am trying to figure out how to use GREP to add comma (`,`) and Dollar sign (`$`) to numbers in InDesign.

For example,

- A GREP configuration to turn 4 digit numbers such as `2000` into `$2,000`
- A GREP configuration to turn 5 digits numbers such as `20000` into `$20,000`

Comment: Can you provide some of your code or an [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Firstly, open InDesign's `Find/Change` palette by either:

   - Choosing `Edit` > `Find/Change` from the menu bar.
   - Or, type <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> on macOS, or type <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> on Windows.
2. Then, select the `GREP` panel in the `Find/Change` palette.

---

<sub>**TL;DR** Use the solution provided in the **Combining both Solutions A and B** section below. However, please consider the solution provided in the **Also change 6 digit numbers such as `100000` into `$100,000`** section below if that is something you want to do too.</sub>

---

#### Solution A:

> A GREP configuration to turn 4 digit numbers such as `2000` into `$2,000`

1. In the `"Find What"` area, enter the following pattern:

   ```
   (?<![0-9])([0-9]{1})([0-9]{3})(?![0-9]+?)
   ```

   A detailed explanation of this regexp pattern can be found [here](https://regex101.com/r/aAYiyY/1).
2. In the `"Change To"` area enter the following:

   ```
   $$1,$2
   ```

---

#### Solution B:

> A GREP configuration to turn 5 digits numbers such as `20000` into `$20,000`

1. In the `"Find What"` area, enter the following pattern:

   ```
   (?<![0-9])([0-9]{2})([0-9]{3})(?![0-9]+?)
   ```

   A detailed explanation of this regexp pattern can be found [here](https://regex101.com/r/aAYiyY/2).
2. In the `"Change To"` area enter the following:

   ```
   $$1,$2
   ```

---

#### Combining both Solutions A and B:

To achieve your requirement you can utilize the following single regexp pattern to perform a single *"Find/Replace"*. This handles both requirements, i.e. it changes numbers such as `2000` into `$2,000` and also handles changing numbers such as `20000` into `$20,000`

1. In the `"Find What"` area, enter the following pattern:

   ```
   (?<![0-9])([0-9]{1,2}?)([0-9]{3})(?![0-9]+?)
   ```

   A detailed explanation of this regexp pattern can be found [here](https://regex101.com/r/aAYiyY/3).
2. In the `"Change To"` area enter the following:

   ```
   $$1,$2
   ```

---

#### Also change 6 digit numbers such as `100000` into `$100,000`

If you also wanted to include changing 6 digit numbers such as `100000` into `$100,000` then do the following:

1. In the `"Find What"` area, enter the following pattern:

   ```
   (?<![0-9])([0-9]{1,3}?)([0-9]{3})(?![0-9]+?)
   ```

   A detailed explanation of this regexp pattern can be found [here](https://regex101.com/r/aAYiyY/4).
2. In the `"Change To"` area enter the following:

   ```
   $$1,$2
   ```

---

#### Additional Notes:

1. The `"Change To"` text (i.e. `$$1,$2`) in the aforementioned solutions utilizes `$1` and `$2` to refer to the digits that were matched by the sub-expressions contained in the parenthesis `(...)` of the regexp pattern. The first dollar sign (`$`) and the comma (`,`) is inserted into the resultant text
2. To perform the changes in your document you'll need to click the `"Find"` button followed by the `"Change All"` button.

---

**Edit:**

The author of the OP subsequently asked the following in the comments:

> also one last note, what would I add to the expression to make it search for 9 digit numbers?

After performing the aforementioned solution provided in the **Also change 6 digit numbers such as `100000` into `$100,000`** section consider running a second *Find/Change* using the following configuration:

1. In the `"Find What"` area, enter the following pattern:

   ```
   (?<![0-9])([0-9]{1,3}?)([0-9]{3})([0-9]{3})(?![0-9]+?)
   ```

   A detailed explanation of this regexp pattern can be found [here](https://regex101.com/r/aAYiyY/5).
2. In the `"Change To"` area enter the following:

   ```
   $$1,$2,$3
   ```

So, after performing the two separate Find/Change tasks, i.e.

1. The one provided in **Also change 6 digit numbers such as `100000` into `$100,000`**
2. Followed by this new one provided in the **Edit** section.

You'll handle all numbers/digits ranging from 4 to 9 digits in length.

The placement of the comma's will be as shown in the table below:

```
┏━━━━━━━━┯━━━━━━━━━━━┯━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┯━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┯━━━━━━━━━━━┓
┃ No. of │ Example   │ Example      │                                                        │           ┃
┃ digits │ Before    │ After        │ Find What Pattern                                      │ Change To ┃
┣━━━━━━━━┿━━━━━━━━━━━┿━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┿━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┿━━━━━━━━━━━┫
┃   4    │ 1234      │ $1,234       │                                                        │           ┃
┠────────┼───────────┼──────────────┤                                                        │           ┃
┃   5    │ 12345     │ $12,345      │ (?<![0-9])([0-9]{1,3}?)([0-9]{3})(?![0-9]+?)           │ $$1,$2    ┃
┠────────┼───────────┼──────────────┤                                                        │           ┃
┃   6    │ 123456    │ $123,456     │                                                        │           ┃
┣━━━━━━━━┿━━━━━━━━━━━┿━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┿━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┿━━━━━━━━━━━┫
┃   7    │ 1234567   │ $1,234,567   │                                                        │           ┃
┠────────┼───────────┼──────────────┤                                                        │           ┃
┃   8    │ 12345678  │ $12,345,678  │ (?<![0-9])([0-9]{1,3}?)([0-9]{3})([0-9]{3})(?![0-9]+?) │ $$1,$2,$3 ┃
┠────────┼───────────┼──────────────┤                                                        │           ┃
┃   9    │ 123456789 │ $123,456,789 │                                                        │           ┃
┗━━━━━━━━┷━━━━━━━━━━━┷━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┷━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┷━━━━━━━━━━━┛
```

Comment: How do you take into account currency with decimals?  For example, having table cells that are formatted like 5678.00 and need to reformat to $5,678.00?

Answer (score 0):

In InDesign, you can use this for 4, 5 or 6 numbers.

Find: `(\d+)(?=(\d\d\d)+\b)`
Change: `$$1,`

Comment: If a document includes numbers `>=7` digits this will find/change them too. This produces incorrect results as the placement of the comma seems incorrect. For instance `1234567` becomes `$1234,567` when surely it should be `$1,234,567`? Similarly `123456789` becomes `$123456,789` instead of `£123,456,789`. See [Using Commas with Numbers](https://www.grammar-monster.com/lessons/commas_with_numbers.htm), it states; _"They [commas] are placed every 3 decimal places for numbers larger than 999"_